# Itext adding non equal cells to table

Tags: itext

I'm trying to create Pdf from java using iText.

How Can I Add two cells to a table when the second cell will begin immediate after the first cell , and Not in the middle of the row..?

Right now when creating 2 cells each of them take 50% of the row

Please advice,
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to have the column width change dynamically based on the text it contains, if that's your question.

A quick and simple fix would be to define relative widths

```
new PdfPTable(new float[] { 1, 2 });
```

or

```
table.setWidths(new float[] { 1, 2 });
```

Comment: I managed to do what I want with Phrase instead of PdfPTable.

Thanks anyway!